# If $A$ is idempotent and $B=(I-A)$, then $BA'=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given that $A$ is idempotent and         $B=(I-A)$, then prove that $BA'=I$.

I try this by taking two idempotent matrices..but i am confused

Comment: Just plug the formula for $B$ into the thing you want to prove.

Comment: The question is wrong.  If $A$ is an idempotent matrix other than $0$, $I - A$ has less than full rank, so you certainly can't have $B A' = I$.

Comment: 1) So, what is your question? 2) What do you mean by $A'$?

Comment: $A'$ generally means $A^T$. However the question is wrong.

Comment: Actually this question is asked in university exam ..and A' means A transpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $A^2=A$ and $B=I-A$, you want to prove
$$BA^T=I$$
$$(I-A)A^T=I$$
$$A^T-AA^T=I$$
Left multiplying by $A$ (if $A\neq O$), what you have to prove comes down to
$$AA^T-A(AA^T)=I$$
$$AA^T-(AA)A^T=I$$
$$AA^T-AA^T=I$$
$$O=I$$
Hence the identity is invalid for $A\neq O$.

For $A=O,B=I$, $BA^T=O$. Hence it is not valid for any $A$.

Answer (score 0):

As it stand, this is not correct.

For instance, take

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$

This is an idempotent matrix, but the expression

$(I-A)A'$

will be equal to the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},$

as shown in [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D-%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%7D%7D%29*%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%7D%7D%5ET).